# Using java and Ruby on rails at the same time... possible?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I am currently developing a search engine and I have some implemented algorithms that are written in Java but also I need to get some Database communication which is easy thing in Ruby an Rails. Thus, Is there any way to use both language in the web application development

Regards :)

Comment: expose the search engine as a webservice and call the webservice from ruby? Or just use SOLR, which already has a gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily. You can run Ruby on top of the JVM by using JRuby, or you can have Ruby communicate with Java by using RJB (Ruby-Java Bridge). Or you could reimplement the algorithms in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like JRuby is the sort of thing you're looking for, although I haven't (yet) used it myself.

JRuby with Rails - including guides for Rails 3 
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyOnRails

Making Java calls
https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby

Comment: :D Marnen beat me to it - slow typer :)